# How do I test my water filter?

Tags: gear, backpacking, water-purification

How can you verify that a water filter still works?  I've had one for several years and I suspect it may not be working.  Is there a way to test and make sure that it still filters to the factory specified microns?

My particular filter is a [First Need](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0009RP8T2)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### General information

Unfortunately the only real way to get your water filter checked is to send a water sample to a lab. You may only want to check whether water is still flowing through, but that's quite obvious, isn't it?

An [article](http://www.backpacker.com/gear/experts/ask-kristin/water-filter-working/#sthash.UFodWRs2.dpuf) on [Backpacker Magazine](http://www.backpacker.com) sums it up:

> A tricky question. Is water still flowing through? Then it’s working,
>   at least on some level. Is it removing all the microscopic bugs that
>   you want it to? Can’t answer that one. And the only folks who can are
>   the lab rats who run the tests and analyze them. (...)

However, if you still want it to be checked, send a sample to a state certified lab ([e.g. for the US](https://www.epa.gov/dwlabcert)). You may also want to information about your device on [NSF Int. - The Public Health and Safety Organization](http://info.nsf.org/Certified/dwtu/).

Full credit and further reading to [Consumer Reports](http://www.consumerreports.org/cro/news/2013/05/how-do-i-know-if-my-water-filter-is-working/index.htm):

> If you want to have your purified water checked, send a sample to a
>   state certified lab. Also check with NSF International, a public
>   health and safety certification group, to find out if your filtering
>   devices were properly vetted. (...) 
>   Keep in mind that you should keep your carafe water filter in the
>   refrigerator. A water-filled carafe can become a breeding ground for
>   microorganisms when left at room temperature.

Before you hand in a sample you have to know what your water filter actually does. Use these characteristics to generate "bad" water and put it in the filter to collect the *potential* "good" water as your sample.

> Different purifiers may target specific contaminants, so check your
>   device or contact the manufacturer to see what yours are designed to
>   remove.

### Example: your mentioned filter

For example your water filter was tested with water from irrigation canal from Takanokura dam, Minami-Souma-shi, Fukushima Prefecture.

[image: All the infos needed]
 <sub>This was the test environment for your filter. These are all the information you need to contaminate your water with everything "filterable".</sub>

All the information from the factory test can be found [here (PDF)](http://www.purewateronline.co.uk/files/Radiation%20Test%20Results%20-%20FN-XL-1L.pdf).

### Blue Dye Integrity Test

Note that your specific manufacturer provides a test you can do (they even recommend to do it before each trip): Blue Dye Integrity Test - Testingprocedure to ensure the First Need XL Elite water purifier is in perfect working order.

> **HELPFUL TIPS FOR OPTIMUM USE**
>
> 1. Remember to perform "Blue Dye" Integrity Test before each trip and check that pump is in working order.
> 2. Use the cleanest water available.
> 3. If pumping becomes extra difficult, clean out or replace canister.
> 4. Remember "Matrix Pumping" works (slowly) even with a partially clogged canister.
> 5. Avoid freezing or high shock loads - perform integrity test procedure if canister freezes or receives a shock. If canister freezes it should be thoroughly defrosted before use.
> 6. Store in a clean, dry area away from fumes. Keep Sanitary Cover in place at all times when not purifying water.
> 7. Questions or replacements contact us at 800-441-8166 or www.generalecology.com

<sub>From product's [technical data sheet (PDF)](http://www.purewateronline.co.uk/files/First%20Need%20XL%20Elite%20Installation%20and%20Technical%20Guide.pdf)</sub>

Find instructions here: [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-WIKzivCEg0&noredirect=1) and written [here](http://www.crystalclearwater.com.au/campingwaterpurifiers/portablewaterpurifiers/firstneedxlintegritytest/):

> **The "Blue Dye" Test**
>
> Pump coloured water through the canister as shown.
>
> [image: Blue Dye]
>
> If the purified water is still coloured - even faintly - the internal
>   canister matrix has most likely been damaged and the canister cannot
>   be relied upon under this condition and must be replaced.*
>
> - Note: Because the initial flow from a new purification canister may contain black "fines" from the manufacturing process, it is best to
>     pump at least a litre of water before doing an integrity test to avoid
>     posible confusion.

***Note***: This test is only suitable for this specific product and not a general procedure for water purifiers! Use at your own risk for other models (and imho don't rely on it even for the example purifier First Need XL).